# No print output from openpyxl modules

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm new in coding - trying to figure it out as working on an actual code.

I want to go through all the column titles in the first row, find the one that says "Status" and get the column letter for it.
Supposedly afterwards I will go through all the rows in the spreadsheet and create a new file with rows that only have a certain keyword in the "Status" column.
My Frankenstein is not giving me any errors, but I can't get a printed output for the column letter.
temp_value variable was created with an intention to hold that column letter and use it in some loops/calculations later in the code.

I appreciate your time and hope you might help me out.
P.S. I actively browse through openpyxl official guidelines, but not much luck. I assume my main problem here is inability to plan my code structure - open to any ideas and advise here :)

```
    import openpyxl
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("myfile.xlsx")
    sheet = wb.active
    temp_data = str()

    #TODO: Find "Status" column to sift through only what we need later

    print("Reading through column titles...")

    for column in range (1, 10):
        column_letter = get_column_letter(column)
        if sheet[column_letter+str(column)].value == "Status":
            temp_data = column_letter

    print(temp_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your description you are stating of looping through the columns titles of the **first row**. The code "sheet[column_letter+**str(column)**].value will generate A1,B2,C3...

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("myfile.xlsx")
sheet = wb.active
temp_data = str()

# TODO: Find "Status" column to sift through only what we need later

print("Reading through column titles...")

for column in range(1, 10):
    column_letter = get_column_letter(column)
    if sheet[column_letter + '1'].value == "Status":
        temp_data = column_letter

print(temp_data)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for pointing out that I was looping through not what I wanted - appreciate that! However, it still is not giving me output I want.
1. I did manually check the content of the workbook. The analyzed worksheet is the very first one. 
Column "E" has the value of "Status" in the first row.
Even though I do not get errors, temp_value still prints empty (I get an empty line in my terminal).

Comment: If the workbook has multiple worksheets it might be usefull to have a strict assignment of the sheet.  sheet= wb.get_sheet_by_name('SheetName'). I tested the code with a workbook having only one worksheet and that gave the desired result

Comment: Looks like it is always small details that get me.
It worked! Thank you, specifying the sheet by name did the trick.
(How long is it going to be till my next post... *sigh*)

Answer (score 0):

You'll rarely actually need `get_column_letter` in your own code:

```
for cell in ws[1]:
   if cell.value == "Status":
       print(cell.column_letter)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I will try and check it out as well!